# When a user clicks a button, I dynamically render date input field html5 but can't access event listener such as change

Tags: javascript, html

When a user clicks a button, I dynamically render date input field html5 but can't access event listener such as change

Here is my code:

```
const dateFunction = () => {
    const y = document.getElementById("my-date").value;
    const formattedY =  moment(y).format('dddd, D MMMM, YYYY');
    document.getElementById('serviceDate').innerText = formattedY;
    document.getElementById('hideDate').value = y;
}

document.getElementById('my-date').addEventListener('change', dateFunction);
```

Comment: are you talking about accessing the event object?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the date input?

Comment: I have solve the issue. I was not checking whether the date input is already available into the dom before adding the listener. if (onceOff) { onceOff.addEventListener('change', dateFunction); }enter code here

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to modify the date when a `<button>` element is clicked, so why don't you add a `"click"` event listener to the button instead?

```
var button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", dateFunction);
```

If you're working with an `<input type="date">` and you want to add an event listener for every time that date picker's value is changed, use the `"input"` event instead of the `"change"` event, I find it to be more reliable.

Comment: No, what happens is that a user clicks two button. One is called once-off, the other is called recurring. When the user clicks the button I show date input field. I manipulate the date on the change event, however, since the input field is loaded dynamically, I can't access the events.

Comment: Could you post the code for that HTML and JS? It's hard to work with what you've given

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse"
                                            data-target="#onceoff">Yes it is
                                    </button>

Comment: If you create the input field using JS DOM manipulation you can still access events using event listeners?

Comment: That's the issue I am experiencing with date input filed. I have zero events to listen to

Comment: Then can you  try executing your code in the line right after you set the value of the `<input type="date">`

Comment: I have solve the issue.
I was not checking whether the date input is already available into  the dom before adding the listener.

 if (onceOff) {
                onceOff.addEventListener('change', dateFunction);
            }`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the issue. I was not checking whether the date input field is already available in the dom before adding the listener.

let onceOff = document.getElementById('once-off-date');

```
if (onceOff) {
               onceOff.addEventListener('change', dateFunction);
           }
```